# Music in "Heaven sent" episode of Doctor Who

Tags: doctor-who, music-identification

In that episode, straight after the **Doctor Who** theme, the Doctor speaks out loud about it being a long range teleporter and that Clara asked to not take revenge but he doesn't always listen.

Can someone tell me the name of the background music that plays just before notices the shovel ?

Comment: are you talking about this one, [Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKGGLi6ubQ4). If yes, you can download this with [keepvid](http://www.keepvid.com) or [youtube-mp3 converter](http://www.youtube-mp3.org/)

Answer (score 5):

All of the music in "Heaven Sent" was composed by Murray Gold, specifically for the episode. <strike>At this point the name of the piece is not public knowledge. For a name you'll have to wait for the Series 9 soundtrack or its track listing, which aren't likely to come soon.</strike>

In the mean time - someone has uploaded a sound clip from the episode with partial voice cancellation to YouTube: [Unreleased Music - The Mysterious Castle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQRUxQ5IRas). This track is not present in the video linked in the other answer.

**EDIT:** The Series 9 soundtrack is out as of April 27, 2018. The album is available on Spotify at [spotify:album:6akYPKZA8VbD9Hmj6q21fN](https://open.spotify.com/album/6akYPKZA8VbD9Hmj6q21fN), though it seems the music you're asking about falls between tracks 1 and 2 and isn't on it. :(

Comment: The series 9 soundtrack will be released in 2018 and one CD will just have the music from this episode: http://www.doctorwhotv.co.uk/series-9-soundtrack-confirmed-for-release-in-2018-86634.htm

Comment: It should be available now. But the copyright situation on YouTube seems to still be complicated.

Comment: [Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/Doctor-Who-Original-Television-Soundtrack/dp/B07BWGQGFC/ref=tmm_msc_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1526424768&sr=8-1) has the season 9 sound track in streaming, MP3, and CD formats. Based on the link from @Fabian the third disc should be all music from _Heaven Sent_.